# SQL Server : How to combine multiple database into one database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

From my original database, I made changes to some tables with columns in the table, I want to merge them into a single database. New database just add some table and old table add some columns.

How to merge multiple database into one database?

SQL example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item]
(
    [ItemID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Money] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ItemName] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [MoneyType] [bigint] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ItemID] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account]
(
    [Index] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [AccountName] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemList] [int] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Money]
(
    [AccountID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Money] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [MoneyType] [bigint] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Money] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AccountID] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

-> Nick.McDermaid: use the schema compare tool in Visual Studio (various free editions) which will create a change script!

Comment: Create the database...then add at the begining of your script `use yourdatabasename,`

Comment: Do you want to merge _data_ or _table definitions_. For table definitions use the schema compare tool in Visual Studio (various free editions) which will create a change script for you

Answer (score 0):

This will combine them onto DBCombined.Account if the Account table does NOT exist yet: the SELECT INTO code creates the target table. You would then need to add any indexes from the original tables. Also, "SELECT *" should really be broken out, listing each field, because if you have an ID field it will contain duplicates. Better to leave ID off during the insert and then go back and add an identity column.

```
USE DBCombined
GO

SELECT *
INTO Account
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM DB1.dbo.Account
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM DB2.dbo.Account
    ) Acct
```

Comment: I will try to list the all table and write new query.
Big database with more tables will take some time.